# Airy transform of gaussian on half-line: $\int_{0}^\infty dx\, e^{-x^2}\text{Ai}(y-x)$

Tags: integration, special-functions, airy-functions

**Background.** The Airy transform of $f$ is defined as
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, f(x)\,\text{Ai}(y-x)\;.$$
$\text{Ai}$ denotes Airy function,
$$\text{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\,\cos(xt+t^3/3)\;.$$
It satisfies Airy equation $\text{Ai}(x)''=x\,\text{Ai}(x)$.

The Airy transform of a gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ can be found explicitly, and it equals
$$\sqrt\pi\, e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(y+\frac{1}{24}\right)}\,\text{Ai}\left(y+\frac{1}{16}\right)\;.$$
For a reference see pp. 77-78 of "Airy Functions and Applications to Physics". You can find a preview [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=Rms5FnMuKEgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

**My question**. Is there some way to use this result to compute the similar integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty dx\, e^{-x^2}\text{Ai}(y-x)\;,$$
where now integration is only on the half-line? Or, anyway, can this integral be given a closed-form expression?

Comment: would u mind to give a reference for a proof of ur first result? this might help to get some ideas about your integral

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. The idea is to use the integral representation of the Airy function, do first the integral in $x$, which is a gaussian integral, and then make the Airy function reappear in the remaining integral. This works well on the whole line, otherwise you cannot do the gaussian integral and everything is lost.

Comment: @tired: the FT of the Airy function is proportional to $e^{i k^3/3}$.